# animating div elements left to right and back

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a menu system made up of divs and i want to animate the left property to slide each time the user mouses over a menu item but i need the outer div(which is black) element to expand as the menu items move left to right also I want the div element(.container) to slide back and contract the outer div element(this black div which is 0 width) I have a basic example done in [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ra7Q6/)  it olny moves the elements to the left

Comment: Can you state more clearly what you have and what you want?

Comment: they animate left to the right...?

Comment: How do I return from mousenter statement when i have no next elelement .container in my example on jsFiddle http://jsfiddle.net/ra7Q6/

Comment: Just to clarify - are you referring to the div that is already expanded snaps back and expands again while it should sit there idle?

Comment: @Jobsz yes that the problem and @kingjiv sorry but i need an answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should be able to fix the left is null issue by having the code not execute on the last .content, like this:

```
$('.container').not(':last').find('.menu-item').mouseenter(function () {
```

This will not apply to the menu-items within the green box.

For the re-show issue, I would change the way you are showing.  Instead of sliding the box out from behind the other, you can position it where you want it to end up and hide it, then you can use:

```
.animate({width: 'show'})
```

Which will give a similar sliding effect.

That, or do it similar to my response to your other question, only without the collapsing I had previously:

http://jsfiddle.net/V3RHr/3/

Answer (score 2):

Having a little trouble fully understanding, but is this sort of what you mean?

http://jsfiddle.net/V3RHr/2/

Comment: not quite like this http://jsfiddle.net/ra7Q6/ but i get an error when i get to the last menu items it says offset()left is null

Answer (score 1):

If I could rewrite your html a bit, I would put make each `.menu-item` into an unordered list.

When you mouseenter the unordered list, you expand the second container. Inside that mouseenter function, I would have a second event when you mouseenter a list item, you populate the second container and stopPropogation.

You could probably still do it with a mouseenter on the first container, and another mouseenter on the `div.menu-item`, but your first container has extra height and width.

Comment: they all will have the same height and width in the end Im just using thos as guides but what do you mean stopPrpogation can u give me an example all I want to be able todo is stop the animation