# error offset().left in null or not an object

Tags: javascript, jquery

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [animating div elements left to right and back](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5891652/animating-div-elements-left-to-right-and-back)

Im getting this error in my code it's todo with the offset().left() when the code is asking for the next .container element in my jquery code i tried using a return statement but it didn't swork. it on the animate line [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ra7Q6/) and how do i stop the animation aswell cos it restarts it if you mouse over another menu item