# how do i stop this animation

Tags: javascript, jquery

> **Possible Duplicates:**
>   [error offset().left in null or not an object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5892027/error-offset-left-in-null-or-not-an-object)
>   [animating div elements left to right and back](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5891652/animating-div-elements-left-to-right-and-back)

I have this slowly working on [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ra7Q6/2/) but i need to stop the animation once the div.container has moved left at the moment it just moves left again when you mouse over the menu item